# c getline() - how do I parse a line?

Tags: c, getline

I'm at a loss as far as how to parse the line in getline(). I would like look at each char that is in the line.

So if someone were to type in: "Hello" into stdin, I'd like to be able to able to access the char array in this manner:

```
line[0] = 'H' 
line[1] = 'e' 
line[2] = 'l'
line[3] = 'l'
line[4] = 'o'
line[5] = '/0';
```

I've looked at getchar(), but I want to try and use getline() as I feel like it is more convenient. I've also looked at scanf(), but it skips whitespaces and doesn't let me parse the input as nicely as getchar() or getline().

Here is simple code that attempts at getting the first char of a line via stdin, but results in a seg fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                               

int main()                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                 
  int len;                                                                                                        
  int nbytes = 100;                                                                                               
  char *line = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);                                                                      

  while(getline(&line, &nbytes, stdin) > 0){                                                                      
    printf("first char: %s", line[0]);  //try and get the first char from input

    /**
     * other code that would traverse line, and look at other chars 
     */                                                                         
  };                                                                                                              

  return 0;                                                                                                       
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `printf("first char: %s", line[0]);` should be `printf("first char: %c", line[0]);`, I think.

Comment: Why are you using string specifier for first element in `line`?

Comment: New to C. That is why. :)

Comment: There is no need to cast `void*` to `char*` explicitly (around `malloc`). This is C, not C++, baby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `%c` format specifier to print out a single character.

The code

```
printf("first char: %s", line[0])
```

will try to treat `line[0]` as the address of a char array.  If you just want to print out the first character, change it to

```
printf("first char: %c", line[0])
//                   ^
```

There are a couple of other small changes you could consider in other parts of your code:

- you don't need to cast the return from malloc
- you should `free(line)` after your while loop

Comment: That worked. Apologies for the oversight. Need to look at printf more carefully next time.

Comment: Absolutely no need to apologise - this was a perfectly valid question to ask.  BTW, I've updated my answer with a couple of other small points that might be useful